# Transpose linq results

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a troubles with linq.

I need to get from this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Package | WorkDay | Hours |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Pack1   | 03/01   |     8 |
| Pack1   | 03/01   |     7 |
| Pack1   | 03/02   |     6 |
| Pack2   | 03/02   |     4 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

to this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       | 03/01 | 03/02 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Pack1 |    15 |     6 |
| Pack2 |     0 |     4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

where cell value is the SUM of Hours for that Package for that WorkDay.

This code DOES work, but it produces wrong table layout:

```
        var query = Time
            .GroupBy(t => new { t.PackageId, t.WorkDay })
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Package = t.FirstOrDefault().Package,
                WorkDay = t.FirstOrDefault().WorkDay,
                Hours = t.Sum(x => x.Hours)
            });
```

Maybe there is a way to transpose query results? Im not sure how to achieve my goal in elegant way.
Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Can you show us what layout the statement above produces?

Comment: What is the end use?  Grid components and reports are _much_ better at pivoting data then Linq and SQL are.

Comment: @GVashist it produces same layout with needed info, but not in the way I need it:    
     +---------+---------+-------+
     | Package | WorkDay | Hours |
     +---------+---------+-------+
     | Pack1   | 03/01   |    15 |
     | Pack1   | 03/02   |     6 |
     | Pack2   | 03/02   |     4 |
     +---------+---------+-------+
Tables doesnt work in comments?

Comment: @DStanley I need it for something like this: http://i.imgur.com/QAKTdap.png

Comment: If you're wondering what the duplicate question is, look for "Pivot tables using LINQ"

Comment: @Servy I didnt now that it called pivoting! Thank you very much for answer. (problem solved I hope)